# Neural network output in c++

Tags: c++, neural-network

I want to create a function that calculates neural network output. The elements of my NN
is  a 19D input vector and a 19D output vector. I choose one hidden layer with 50 neurons. My code is the following but i am not quite sure if it works properly.

```
double *BuildPlanner::neural_tactics(){


    norm();  //normalize input vector
    ReadFromFile();   // load weights W1 W2 b1

    double hiddenLayer [50][1];


    for(int h=0; h<50; h++){
            hiddenLayer[h][0] =0;
            for(int f = 0; f < 19; f++){

                    hiddenLayer[h][0] = hiddenLayer[h][0] + W1[h][f]*input1[f][0];
            }
    }

    double HiddenLayer[50][1];

    for(int h=0; h<50; h++){
            HiddenLayer[h][0] = tanh(hiddenLayer[h][0] + b1[h][0]);
    }

    double outputLayer[50][1];

    for(int h=0; h<19; h++){
            for(int k=0; k<50; k++){
                    outputLayer[h][0] = outputLayer[h][0] + W2[h][k]*HiddenLayer[k][0];
            }
    }

    double Output[19];

    for(int h=0; h<19; h++){

            Output[h] = tanh(outputLayer[h][0]);
    }

    return Output;
}
```

Actually I not quite sure about the matrices multiplication. W1*input+b1 where the size
of the matrices are 50x19 * 19x1 + 50x1 and  W2*outHiddenLayer 19x50*50x1!

Comment: You could start by not hardcoding all those sizes, so you can easily plug in some small numbers and go through the result by hand.

Comment: Yea its a good start. But actually my problem is if multiplications works as the way i want!

Comment: Check this library: http://sourceforge.net/projects/c-c-neural-networks/

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix multiplication looks ok to me, but there are other problems--`outputLayer is 50x1 but a) you only iterate through the first 19 elements, and b) you have it on the RHS of your equation

`outputLayer[h][0] = outputLayer[h][0] + W2[h][k]...`

before that element has ever been defined.  That could be causing all your problems.  Also, although I assume you're making `outputLayer` 2-dimensional to make them look matrix-like, it's completely gratuitous and slows things down when the second dimension has size 1--just declare it and the others as

`double outputLayer[50];`

since it's a vector and those are always one dimensional so it will actually make your code clearer.

Comment: outputLayer  the output of NN has 19x1 size. Wrong definition! Just forgot to change 50 to 19!!

Comment: @FereRes Ok. But of course b) is really the main problem and would explain why your results are 'weird'--using undefined values won't in this case create compile- or run-time errors, but just lead to undefined behavior.